# Convert glob to `find`

Tags: find, wildcards

I have again and again had this problem: I have a glob, that matches exactly the correct files, but causes `Command line too long`. Every time I have converted it to some combination of `find` and `grep` that works for the particular situation, but which is not 100% equivalent.

For example:

```
./foo*bar/quux[A-Z]{.bak,}/pic[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?.jpg
```

Is there a tool for converting globs into `find` expressions that I am not aware of? Or is there an option for `find` to match the glob without matching a the same glob in a subdir (e.g. `foo/*.jpg` is not allowed to match `bar/foo/*.jpg`)?

Comment: Expand the brace and you should be able to use the resultant expressions with `-path` or `-ipath`. `find . -path './foo*bar/quux[A-Z]/pic[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?.jpg'` should work - except that it will match `/fooz/blah/bar/quuxA/pic1234d.jpg`. Will that be a problem?

Comment: Yes, that will be a problem. It has to be 100% equivalent.

Comment: The problem is that we have no idea, what is exactly the difference. Your pattern is pretty okay.

Comment: I added your extension post as an answer to the question. I hope it is not so bad.

Comment: Can't you do `echo <glob> | cat`, assuming my knowledge of bash, echo is build-in, and thus doesn't have the max command limit

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the problem is that you get an argument-list-is-too-long error, use a loop, or a shell built-in. While `command glob-that-matches-too-much` can error out, `for f in glob-that-matches-too-much` does not, so you can just do:

```
for f in foo*bar/quux[A-Z]{.bak,}/pic[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?.jpg
do
    something "$f"
done
```

The loop might be excruciatingly slow, but it should work.

Or:

```
printf "%s\0" foo*bar/quux[A-Z]{.bak,}/pic[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?.jpg |
  xargs -r0 something
```

(`printf` being builtin in most shells, the above works around the limitation of the `execve()` system call)

```
$ cat /usr/share/**/* > /dev/null
zsh: argument list too long: cat
$ printf "%s\n" /usr/share/**/* | wc -l
165606
```

Also works with bash. I'm not sure exactly where this is documented though.

---

Both Vim's [`glob2regpat()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#glob2regpat%28%29) and Python's [`fnmatch.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.translate) can convert globs to regexes, but both also use `.*` for `*`, matching across `/`.

Comment: If that is true, then replacing `something` with `echo` ought to do it.

Comment: @OleTange That's why I suggested `printf` - it will be faster than calling `echo` thousands of times, and offers more flexibility.

Comment: How can the line be too long for `cat` but not `printf`? What do you get if you do `/bin/cat` instead?

Comment: There’s a limit on the arguments that can be passed through `exec`, which applies to external commands such as `cat`; but that limit doesn’t apply to shell builtin commands such as `printf`.

Comment: @OleTange The line is not too long because `printf` is a builtin, and the shells presumably use the same method for supplying arguments to it that they use for enumerating arguments for `for`. `cat` is not a builtin.

Comment: Technically there are shells like `mksh` where `printf` is not builtin and shells like `ksh93` where `cat` is (or can be) builtin. See also `zargs` in `zsh` to work around it without having to resort to `xargs`.

Comment: I suppose the principle question is whether the shells glob lazily (say, with an effect like Python's `yield` - the next match is obtained when asked for), or greedily, collating all matches at once.

Comment: `ksh93`'s `printf` can also convert wildcards to regexps (`printf "%R\n" "*.txt"` outputs `\.txt$`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas how does it treat `*` in the middle of a path? `.*` or `[^/]*`?

Comment: `.*`. The `*` wildcard matches on any sequence of characters. It's the way globs use wildcard to generate files that  make them not match `/` (in `*/*` the `*`s are only matched against file names in a given directory, so will never  see any`/` character).

Comment: @Stéphane that's the same problem as with the other converters I mentioned - they match more than the glob

Comment: Yes, you'd need to tell `find` to match and prune file names at all the levels which is generally  not practical (see note in my answer), or use `-depth <x>` to make sure only paths at a given depth are considered (but would still cause `find` to  look into directories it shouldn't need to).

Comment: ty 4 `printf "%s\n" /usr/share/**/*`

Answer (score 10):

`find` (for the `-name`/`-path` standard predicates) uses wildcard patterns just like globs (note that `{a,b}` is not a glob operator; after expansion, you get two globs). The main difference is the handling of slashes (and dot files and dirs not being treated specially in `find`). `*` in globs won't span several directories. `*/*/*` will cause up to 2 levels of directories to be listed. Adding a `-path './*/*/*'` will match any files that are at least 3 levels deep and won't stop `find` from listing the contents of any directory at any depth.

For that particular

```
./foo*bar/quux[A-Z]{.bak,}/pic[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?.jpg
```

couple of globs, it's easy to translate, you're wanting directories at depth 3, so you can use:

```
find . -mindepth 3 -maxdepth 3 \
       \( -path './foo*bar/quux[A-Z].bak/pic[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?.jpg' -o \
          -path './foo*bar/quux[A-Z]/pic[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?.jpg' \) \
       -exec cmd {} +
```

Or POSIXly:

```
find . -path './*/*/*' -prune \
       \( -path './foo*bar/quux[A-Z].bak/pic[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?.jpg' -o \
          -path './foo*bar/quux[A-Z]/pic[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?.jpg' \) \
       -exec cmd {} +
```

Which would guarantee that those `*` and `?` could not match `/` characters.

(`find`, contrary to globs would read the content of directories other than `foo*bar` ones in the current directory¹, and not sort the list of files. But if we leave aside the problem that what is matched by `[A-Z]` or the behaviour of `*`/`?` with regards to  invalid characters is unspecified, you'd get the same list of files).

But in any case, as [@muru has shown](/a/386900), there's no need to resort to `find` if it's just for splitting the list of files into several runs to work around the limit of the `execve()` system call. Some shells like `zsh` (with `zargs`) or `ksh93` (with `command -x`) even have builtin support for that.

With `zsh` (whose globs also have the equivalent of `-type f` and most other `find` predicates), for instance:

```
autoload zargs # if not already in ~/.zshrc
zargs ./foo*bar/quux[A-Z](|.bak)/pic[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?.jpg(.) -- cmd
```

(`(|.bak)` is a glob operator contrary to `{,.bak}`, the `(.)` glob qualifier is the equivalent of `find`'s `-type f`, add `oN` in there to skip the sorting like with `find`, `D` to include dot-files (doesn't apply to this glob))

---

¹ For `find` to crawl the directory tree like globs would, you'd need something like:

```
find . ! -name . \( \
  \( -path './*/*' -o -name 'foo*bar' -o -prune \) \
  -path './*/*/*' -prune -name 'pic[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?.jpg' -exec cmd {} + -o \
  \( ! -path './*/*' -o -name 'quux[A-Z]' -o -name 'quux[A-Z].bak' -o -prune \) \)
```

That  is *prune* all directories at level 1 except the `foo*bar` ones, and all at level 2 except the `quux[A-Z]` or `quux[A-Z].bak` ones, and then select the `pic...` ones at level 3 (and prune all directories at that level).

Answer (score 3):

You could write a regex for find matching your requirements:

```
find . -regextype egrep -regex './foo[^/]*bar/quux[A-Z](\.bak)?/pic[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][^/]?\.jpg'
```

Comment: Is there a tool that does this conversion to avoid human errors?

Comment: No, but the only changes I made were to escape `.`, add the optional match for `.bak` and change `*` to `[^/]*` to not match paths like /foo/foo/bar etc.

Comment: But even your conversion is wrong. ? is not changed into [^/]. This is exactly the kind of human error I want to avoid.

Comment: I think with egrep, you can shorten `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?` to `[0-9]{3,4}`

Comment: @OleTange See [Create regex from glob expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/445910/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

Generalising on the note on [my other answer](/a/386909), as a more direct answer to your question, you could use this POSIX `sh` script to convert  the glob to a `find` expression:

```
#! /bin/sh -
glob=${1#./}
shift
n=$#
p='./*'

while true; do
  case $glob in
    (*/*)
      set -- "$@" \( ! -path "$p" -o -path "$p/*" -o -name "${glob%%/*}" -o -prune \)
      glob=${glob#*/} p=$p/*;;
    (*)
      set -- "$@" -path "$p" -prune -name "$glob"
      while [ "$n" -gt 0 ]; do
        set -- "$@" "$1"
        shift
        n=$((n - 1))
      done
      break;;
  esac
done
find . "$@"
```

To be used with *one* standard `sh` glob (so not the  two globs of your example which uses *brace expansion*):

```
glob2find './foo*bar/quux[A-Z].bak/pic[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]?.jpg' \
  -type f -exec cmd {} +
```

(that doesn't ignore dot-files or dot-dirs except `.` and `..` and doesn't sort the list of  files).

That one only works with globs relative to the current directory, with no `.` or `..` components. With some effort, you could extend it to any glob, more than a glob... That could also be optimised so that `glob2find 'dir/*'` doesn't look for `dir` the same was as it would for a pattern.